# ZipFile Kotlin class returns java.io.FileNotFoundException: File doesn't exist

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning how to work with zip files in Kotlin. In theory my app should read files from zip and extract them if needed. For this task I use java.util.zip.ZipFile, but when I pass a file I choose, the app crashes, saying the file doesn't exist.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val intent = Intent()
            .setType("*/*")
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 111)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedFile = data?.data

            var file = File(selectedFile!!.path)
            var zipFile = ZipFile(file)
        }
    }
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File doesn't exist: /document/acc=1;doc=155

Comment: That path doesn't look valid. What does `file.exists()` return? What documentation are you referring to in regard to what exactly should be passed via `data.data` from the GET_CONTENT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ZipFile` only works with files, while the result of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is an Uri, from which you can usually *not* get a file (see [How to Consume Content From a Uri](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) for a detailed explanation).

There are two solutions :

- Use a [`ZipInputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream), which can extract the content of a stream.
- Copy the stream from the Uri to a local file, then open it with the `ZipFile`